# How to solve these types of combinatorics problems?

Tags: combinatorics

Amita has three library cards and seven books of her interest in the library of Mindworkzz. Of these books she would not like to borrow the D.I. book, unless the Quants book is also borrowed. In how many ways can she take the three books to be borrowed
I am getting answer 15 but the actual answer is 25.

Comment: how did you get to your answer?

Comment: It would be appreciated it if you could show us your work as to how you got your answer so that we can have something to go off of and tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: My guess:  Your count improperly neglects the cases in which Quants is borrowed but DI is not.

Answer (score 3):

The total number of ways to choose the books is $\binom73$.

The number of ways to choose the D.I. book but not the Quants book is $\binom52$.

Hence the number of ways to choose the books under that restriction is $\binom73-\binom52$.

Comment: can you explain me how you did The number of ways to choose the D.I. book but not the Quants book is (5c2).

Comment: @TarunTanmay: A better way to say $\binom52$ here is $\binom{7-\color\red2}{3-\color\green1}$. Do you understand now? The "$\color\red2$" indicates the $2$ books that you cannot choose. You will use one of them as part of your $3$ books. The "$\color\green1$" indicates the one that you will use. So in short, you have $3-1=2$ remaining books to choose, and $7-2=5$ remaining books to choose **from**.